# Is it possible to prevent usage of personal (user) repositories in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to prevent usage of personal (user) repositories in gitlab?

I just want them to use groups/teams and not to create personal repositories?

One of the reasons for this is that this creates all the repos inside the same directory, combined with the group ones and in fact we have no need to personal ones.

Comment: Have you tried setting the default project limit to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Personal repositories are a great tool for doing investigative or POC work without cluttering production repositories with code that will never intended to go to production.  From an operations perspective, this is important.  It is easy for any team member, and more so for new team members, to accidentally open a POC project with a name similar to a production app that may come out of that POC and patch/deploy POC code by mistake.  Keep them separate.  Breaking production is avoidable if you have a thorough set of automated regression tests (and almost no one does) but the lost time finding the right project or accidentally working in the wrong project is inevitable if you don't allow personal repositories.

To make sure that production code only comes from production repositories, just make sure your production Jenkins instance only has access to your production repos.  This ensures that developers must move what started as POC code to the production repo before the code is deployed to production.